Скомпилированный sql запрос
Как можно увидеть, в какой sql запрос компилируется запрос из flask-sqlalchemy?

К сожалению, человек, ответивший на мой вопрос, удалил свой ответ, но я успел прочитать его. Смысл в том, что в конфигурационном файле можно установить параметр, например, SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True и raw sql будет выводиться в консоль после каждого запроса
